# polyphase sample rate conversion with non-integer factor

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I have designed a sample rate conversion filter h[n], with matlab's filterbuilder for interpolation factor I=5, and decimation factor D=9. Since D>I, matlab will design a filter with cutoff frequency pi/D.

Then I converted the designed filter h[n] into I=5 polyphase filters, using matlab's method polyphase(). However, I noticed that the coefficients of each seperate polyphase filter do not sum to 1. Hence, I cannot compute valid interpolated sample points. How is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a *wrong* place to post this, but dsp.stackexchange.com is definately the *best* place to post it. Unfortunately, you can't seem to flag it to be moved there... I flagged it to be moved to meta -- hopefully the moderator will figure it out. Feel free to delete this question and re-ask on dsp.se.com

Comment: Migrate to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

See my post at: [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/polyphase-sample-rate-conversion-with-non-integer-factor/10357#10357%20%22dsp.stackexchange.com) for an answer to this question, and a guide on how to design a sample rate converter with non-integer factor.